What is this problem with computation of large integers?
The following equation is same as doing nothing to the integer
((as.bigz(27080235094679553)+1028)*2)/2 - 1028

However, the answer to this in console is 27080235094679552. To get the correct answer I need to subtract 1027 instead of 1028. What's the issue here?
I tried using the mfpr package as well but it did not work.

basically,  ?as.bigz will answer this for you

When you enter 27080235094679553 as a numeric constant as the argument to as.bigz, R first parses the number and stores it as a double-precision float. You need to enter the value as character so it doesn't get messed up:
library(gmp)
((as.bigz("27080235094679553")+1028)*2)/2 - 1028
## Big Rational ('bigq') :
## [1] 27080235094679553

As a further illustration:
print(27080235094679553, digits = 22)
## [1] 27080235094679552

The same issue would apply when using Rmpfr.
(As pointed out in the comments, ?gmp::as.bigz has this note:

x <- as.bigz(1234567890123456789012345678901234567890)
will not work as R converts the number to a double, losing
precision and only then convert[ing] to a ‘"bigz"’ object.

Instead, use the syntax
x <- as.bigz("1234567890123456789012345678901234567890")

)

Thank you for the solution. I had another follow up question on this. How would I convert the numbers in a column of a dataframe in bigz format so that any future operations on it as shown in the original post will not lose precision. any leads would be appreciated. ChatGPT and Claude AI gave me incorrect solutions

I think you should post that as a follow-up question, with a minimal example. dd <- data.frame(z=as.bigz(c("1", "2"))) does give a data frame with a column of type bigz ...
